# The best way of develop with Open shift origin: VM or local installation

Tags: openshift-origin

What is the best way to develop with open shift origin? Is it using vm or install it locally? I have tried installing the vm and I could not login to the vm. What is the default credential used to login to fedora vm.

Comment: So, not clear what is the question: best way to choose or default password for fedora? Could please give some idea of what is open shift origin? And what are criteriums do you have during choosing of variants?

Comment: I need both answers please

OpenShift Origin is an application platform where developers and teams can build, test, deploy, and run their applications. OpenShift Origin also serves as the upstream code base upon which OpenShift Online and OpenShift Enterprise are built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Default credentials**
Depending on which route you follow (see below) there might or might not be *real* authorization in place.

If you have the [AllowAllPasswordIdentityProvider](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/configuring_authentication.html#AllowAllPasswordIdentityProvider) in place you can get away with test/test or whatever.

If you take the binary version (see below) this is what you'll have by default. I changed it to be [HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/configuring_authentication.html#HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider) instead.

For the other options I think you will have a user called **system**, with the password **admin** coming with the setup.

**Docker container version**

> You can quickly get OpenShift running in a Docker container using
> images from Docker Hub on a Linux system. This method is supported on
> Fedora, CentOS, and Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) hosts only.

Link: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/getting_started/administrators.html#running-in-a-docker-container

As per the origin folks, this setup is not (yet) a full example, but very easy to get started with. You should be able to follow the instructions to get an all-in-one instance up and running in no time. However, this approach cannot teach you how to create a cluster (master(s) and node(s))

**Vagrant VM**

> This image is based off of OpenShift Origin and is a fully functioning
> OpenShift instance with an integrated Docker registry. The intent of
> this project is to allow Web developers and other interested parties
> to run OpenShift V3 on their own computer. Given the way it is
> configured, the VM will appear to your local machine as if it was
> running somewhere off the machine.
>
> The OpenShift Master, Node, Docker Registry, and other pieces are running in one VM. Given it's focus on application developers, it should NOT be used in production.

Link: https://www.openshift.org/vm

**Binary option**

> Red Hat periodically publishes binaries to GitHub, which you can
> download on the OpenShift Origin Releases page.

Link: https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases

This is the option I follow currently. You download the binaries, install GO, then setup the OC client tools. Next step you generate the configuration files and start adding your system components (router, ...).

Follow this page to understand the basics:
Link: https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/examples/sample-app/README.md

**Ansible route**

For production installation you probably want to install your cluster via Ansible.

My humble advice is to do this once you got a bit of an experience via configuring by hand (see previous point). Let's hear some people with more experience though.

Link: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/index.html

**Documentation in general**

Link: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/master_node_configuration.html#creating-new-configuration-files

Comment: Thanks for your answer; now i go with the vm option, after i got familiar with open shift origin i will go with the binary option.

Answer (score 0):

Spin up a Centos.7 VM, download the latest origin tools:

```
wget https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/download/v1.3.0-alpha.2/openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.3.0-alpha.2-983578e-linux-64bit.tar.gz
tar xzvf openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.3.0-alpha.2-983578e-linux-64bit.tar.gz
ln -s /root/openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.3.0-alpha.2-983578e-linux-64bit/oc /usr/local/bin/oc
chmod 755 /root/openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.3.0-alpha.2-983578e-linux-64bit/oc
```

Bring up your single node origin cluster:

```
oc cluster up --use-existing-config --host-data-dir=/var/tmp/etcd
```

Login using the instructions provided.